# Using two int variables in one command in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a very simple question but I can't seem to figure this out.  I want to add ".00" in front of my "float l" variable before doing my final calculations.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
float x = ([nitrogen.text floatValue]);
float l = ([ml.text floatValue]);
int r =  x * 10000;
int t = .00;  //code added to add .00 in front of ML final output??
int e = t.l;
float f = r * t.l; // I've tried t&&l and others.. it doesn't work... help!!!
```

So for example if l = "5".. i want to make l = ".005" instead.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C, this would be much better done with something like

```
t = (l / 1000);
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.%03d", r, t];
```

And if you really want to stuff the result into a float named `f`, you could even do:

```
t = (l / 1000);
NSString * someString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.%03d", r, t];
f = [someString floatValue];
```

Since you tagged this with a `c` tag and not Objective-C, I'm certain you'll get lots of other (and probably even better and/or more algorithmic) opinions.

Comment: Thank you guys for a very quick answer.  However, is there still a way that I cant string two variables TOGETHER without doing any calculations?  For example.....  if R equaled 20 and E equaled 50.. what code would I use to have the compilers display "2050" together as one string??

Comment: you can do it completely using the `stringWithFormat` method in `NSString`.  If R = 20 & E = 50, you could do `NSString * someString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d%d", R, E];` and you'd get "`2050`".  B.T.W., you would get the result you want, but if there's anything unexpected in the variables (like E = -50), you'd get unexpected and unappreciated results ("`20-50`").

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll not be in a situation where the user will be typing any negative integars so this will work.  So my final calculation would work even though I set R & E as a NSString?

ex...

    'float f = r * someString'

would that work?

Comment: I want to take the final output (2050) and make a variable operation.. for example this does not work:

    NSString * someString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d%d", R, L];
    int f = x * someString;

Comment: Tim... you're going to need to get very familiar with the differences between Objective C objects (like `NSString`) and C types (like `int` & `float`).  I could provide the answer you're looking for super fast, but everything you need is already here in both my answer and in the answer from @AlexDeem.

Comment: Thank you but only part of the answer I'm looking for is in your post.  I guess I have to be more clear.  How do I multiply someString by X?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sigh. I was trying to help guide you to the answer but here it is:  `int f = (int)(x * [someString floatValue]);` X can be a float or an int and the `(int)` cast in front of the parenthesized equation guarantees the result will fit into f.  You can use `floor` or `ceil` to round the non-casted result up or down.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am fairly new to Objective C and appreciate your helping.  Before you replied I did tinker with my code and got it working but it looks like I took a "long cut" and used more code than I needed to.  Do you have any good web resources that has a idiots view on Objective C?  Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply divide by 1000.

```
float l = ([ml.text floatValue]);
l = l / 1000;  // if l was 5, l will now be 0.005
```